# How to initialize a ListenersList with the owning object while creating

Tags: delphi

I have an Engine, which contains a list of Assemblies. The assemblies are created on initialization of the Engine, from a list of registered AssemblyClasses (so they are fixed at runtime). The assemblies can be triggered to recalculate their result using a ParameterObject.

When the properties of a ParameterObject of an Assembly change or when the recalculation is finished, a notify event (ParameterChanged resp ResultsChanged) is fired to all interfaces in a ListenersList. Each Assembly has its own listenerlist.

The Engine will register itsself as one of the listeners of all the Assemblies, and the problem now is that when an Assembly is created and thus the initial ParameterObject is created and the ParameterChanged event is fired, the Engine has not yet added itself to the listenerslist so it does not get informed of the intial ParameterObject.

What is the best way to solve this? Should I add a reference of the Engine to the constructor (referencing the engine as a Listener as marjan suggested), or maybe call the eventhandler of the engine explicitly after creating each Assembly...

Btw using Delphi XE3

Gratefull for any suggestions

Comment: BTW If anybody can think of a shorter/ more to the point title for this question .. be my guest!

Comment: You could post a message that would trigger an eventhandler call. See [`"delayed-action-revisited"`](http://tech.turbu-rpg.com/454/delayed-action-revisited) for an example how to implement such a thing.

Comment: Who is creating the assemblies? Who is adding listeners to the assemblies? How is the engine notified of a new assembly (so it can register itself)? The answer to your question may be dependent on your current design. When adding a reference to the Engine in the assemblies constructor, consider adding that reference not as an engine, but as a _listener_. That should keep the dependencies to a minimum. With your version of Delphi you also have the option of passing an anonymous listener method to the assembly constructor that the constructor can call when it has finished setting everything up.